# Using LM358 and TIP 122 in a circuit as a constant current driver

Tags: current, driver

I have been working on the constant current driver for a valve. Please find the circuit screenshot below. I am able to observe only 10 mA at the junction where the valve has to be connected. According to the valve datasheet, it actuates only after 60mA. So basically, I need a constant current driver with the range of 0 - 200 mA. The components used in the circuit are the same as mentioned in the schematic. Can someone please guide me on how it can be solved?
[image: Taken from Parker VSO datasheet]

Comment: You need to provide the valve coil resistance and the drive voltage connected to TIP120 collector. Also op-amp supply voltage and valve type would be beneficial. And other resistor values.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Justme Valve coil resistance - 69.4 Ohms, Drive Voltage connected to TIP 120 - 12-14V, Op-amp Supply Voltage - 12V, Valve type - Proportional Valve. Resistor R1 - 5.1k ohms & R2 - 180 ohms. Let me know if you need any more values.

Comment: Specific problem - Need to pass 60 - 200 mA through the valve coil (which enables opening of the valve) but the circuit only gives 10 mA & hence the valve is not opening.

Comment: What exactly do you need to have "solved"? Does the circuit not work? With max. 5 V control voltage there are 170 mV on the positive input of the opamp, hence also on the 1 Ohm resitor, which in turn means that max. 170 mA could flow through it. For me, the only thing that looks wrong, is that the coil should be between drive voltage and collector of tip 120, and not between emitter and the 1 Ohm resistor! Also note, that the opamp will not be able to reach the GND rail, so even with 0 V control a little current might flow through the coil (may not be a real problem). If so, tell us ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Move the valve coil to the TIP120 collector.  This will remove the coil voltage drop from the voltage that the opamp output must exceed to cause the transistor to conduct.  There will be a trivially small difference between the current in the sense resistor and the current in the valve, much less than the component tolerances.

Note that your transistor is a Darlington type.  This also increases the opamp drive voltage necessary for operation.  Nothing you can do about that, and the extra gain is necessary, but it is another reason to shift the valve voltage drop to somewhere where it does not add to the opamp output drive requirements.

Nit-picky:  Six of your components are missing reference designators, so deeper component-level discussions will be difficult.

Please tell us the DC resistance of the valve.  This is critically important in calculating the circuit component values.  Also, what are the valve and opamp supply voltages?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the bottom 1 ohm resistor. All the power circuit current flow thru it, and it's evident that the coil current is the same as the resistor current: the (-) terminal of the opamp is assumed to have infinite input impedance.

So by Ohm's law you have a voltage on the resistor directly proportional to the current. This voltage is also available on the (-) terminal of the amp.

Now, the job of the opamp is always to try to keep the (+) and (-) terminals at the same potential (virtual ground principle). The BJT simply boosts the output current and it's response can be mostly ignored (by magic and/or faith) since it's *inside* the feedback loop.

In short you have to put on the (+) terminal the same voltage you want across the resistor. Since it's 1 ohm it's easy: if you want one ampere, just give in 1V. That's the job for the input divider, you just need it to give the correct voltage from the +5V input signal.

Some considerations:

- Your opamp need to have a common mode reaching the ground since that's where your feedback signal is;
- The 100k input resistor is not really indispensable, it helps decoupling the opamp from the input;
- Solenoid valves are usually not really picky on their working current: consider that the 'input' value could be slightly more on less than 5V, especially if it comes from a logic gate;
- The 5V input is an example, it will work fine with 3.3V logic for example simply using an adequate divider.